# Jekyll autoloading doesn't work

Tags: jekyll

I created a simple blog with Jekyll 3.0.2 and added one post.
I run the server with `jekyll serve --incremental`.
After this I'm trying to make changes in that post but nothing is happening. My post site still looks the same.

Comment: Have you tried `jekyll serve --watch` ?

Comment: yes, I get info that one file has been change, reload browser and no change. I try with grunt.js, maybe that will help

Comment: As you're using a new version of Jekyll (3.x), I suggest you to update it. They've released Jekyll 3.1.0. Try googling about `incremental`; if I'm not mistaken, I've read something related to it in the new v 3.x.  Something might have changed.

Comment: I create fresh blog just for testing purpose and same situation, after every change in post I need to restart the server, which is really annoying

Comment: Really? Even if you set Jekyll to `--watch`? There's something wrong though. Try to run a `jekyll --trace` to see what results will you have.

Comment: Just use `jekyll serve`? If your blog pages have got an error, they will not compile and you will not see the updated page. Please check the output on your console.

Comment: I was reading this [doc](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#incremental-regeneration) and came across to what might answer to your question. What if you add this line to your `_config.yml` : `incremental: true` and then run `jekyll serve --watch` ? Might that be the right way to do that?

Comment: nothing help, I create pull request on jekyll github and get answer, posts're reloading index page not, that's why I don't see changes, I figure out it by using grunt.js and know can easily modify posts.

Comment: **Polling** should work: `jekyll serve --force_polling`

Comment: When you save, if jekyll is generating log on console - its compiler is fine and there had to be some issue with post or installation.

Perform clean built first, one time and see what happens. Set jekyll log to full trace.